# How does Laravel optional() work?

Tags: php, laravel

When creating new models, I am trying to use the `optional()` helper to assign values when they are set. However, when the `user` object isn't set in this context, I receive this error: `"Undefined property: stdClass::$user"`

```
$this->events()->create([
    'category_a' => optional($event)->categoryA,
    'category_b' => optional($event)->categoryB,
    'user' => optional($event->user)->accountId,
]);
```

To clarify, the `$event` is always set, however it can contain different values. Sometimes `category_a` is set, sometimes `category_b` is set. The optional helper seems to do the trick here. But, when the object is deeper than one level, it throws an error.

So how do I work with the `optional` helper correctly using deeper than one level objects?

Comment: Are you asking how it works internally, or about `optional(optional(optional($event)->$first)->$second)`?

Comment: Chaining the `optional()` like that looks pretty ugly and hard to read/maintain. Isn't there any other way of doing it?

Comment: Looking at the source it only goes 1 level deep, as `$event` would be passed as a construct then returned and a __get is fired on that prop `categoryA` so no you cant do `optional($event)->categoryA` if its `$event->foo->categoryA` see code: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/0c6f4740dfa448695b659aae521c6e138c3cf69d/src/Illuminate/Support/Optional.php

Comment: tbh you should be trying to fix/remove the *sometimes* from the code.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The `optional()` helper normally is used to avoid errors generated by accesing propeties or methods on null objects, for example:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function foo() on null

As the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-optional) specifies:

> The optional function accepts any argument and allows you to access properties or call methods on that object.If the given object is null, properties and methods will return null instead of causing an error.

**A practical example**

In your code you are accesing a relation called `address` from your `user` model:

```
return $user->address->street;
```

If by any chance your `$user->address` is null and you try to check the `street`, this will return a fatal error, here is where `optional()` comes into play, by using the helper you can explicitly say `$user->address` *might* be null, so don't show me an error if that's the case:

```
return optional($user->address)->street;
```

By doing this you will get `null` instead of the fatal error.

In my opinion this makes the code more readable, a equivalent could be `$user->address ? $user->address->street : null`, but as you can see is by far more verbose.

In your case, as the comments said an option is to nest `optional()` helpers, but this is not maintanable if you have multiple levels. I'd recommend you to make a function that internally will chain the helpers so your syntax would look like `n_optional($event, ['user'])->accountId`.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I accepted your answer since it answers my question. However, what I ended up doing was using the *null coalescing operator*. `'user' => $event->user->accountId ?? null,`

Comment: @Fredrik `?? == isset`, `?: == is_null`

Comment: @ctf0 Expression expr1 ?: expr3 returns expr1 if expr1 evaluates to true, and expr3 otherwise.

Comment: @yangwendaxia because is_null == false, so both are the same

Answer (score 15):

Also, bear in mind that in PHP 8+ you can use the [null safe operator](https://www.php.net/releases/8.0/en.php#nullsafe-operator) to have the same behavior with cleaner look:

```php
// PHP 8+
$this->events()->create([
    'category_a' => $event?->categoryA,
    'category_b' => $event?->categoryB,
    'user' => $event->user?->accountId,
]);
```

It is also chainable and can be used with methods:

```php
// before PHP 8
$country = null;
if ($session !== null) {
    $user = $session->user;
    if ($user !== null) {
        $address = $user->getAddress();
        if ($address !== null) {
            $country = $address->country;
        }
    }
}

// PHP 8+
$country = $session?->user?->getAddress()?->country;
```

**Note** by @pedro-x: Pay attention that `optional()` works for `null|false` values, while `?->` only works with `null` values. They are not the same! Pay attention to the details to avoid breaking your code.

Comment: I'd argue against this.
Pay attention that `optional()` works for `null|false` values, while php `?` only works with null values. 

They are not the same! Pay attention to the details to avoid breaking your code.

Cheers